# fulltext search against multiple object properties

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I'm using full text search with example below to filter data on FirstName only.  Now I want to extend this example to search data on multiple properties for example `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Country`

```
var data = (from p in session.Query<MyEntityDocyment>()
              .Search(x => x.FirstName, request.search + "*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard)                           
            select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RavenDB, we call it Orders Search. You can see the full details here: http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb